# Need help using navbutton and counter to show & reset array sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, button, counter

My goal is to develop a very simple "make your own story" game engine using script. Right now, this code sufficiently starts the story, but it yields "undefined" after passing the final array in the list. This is frustrating because I'm sure I've stumbled upon the solution several times, but I don't know exactly what to do. I am only supposed to use basic JS for this, so no jquery, php etc. I know there should be a for loop/variable counter in there somewhere.

HTML:

```
<p id="story">Hello.</p>


<input name="NavButton" type="button" 
value="Start" 
onclick= "OnPress();" />
```

JS:

```
function OnPress()
{
document.getElementById("story").innerHTML=myArray[i++];
}


var myArray = new Array();
myArray[0] = "Welcome to the Dark Abyss.";
myArray[1] = "There's a fork in the road. What to do?";
myArray[2] = "The fox doesn't talk much.";
myArray[3] = "Thank Grozia! You survived.";

var i=myArray.indexOf(myArray[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are giving an index that is valid i.e your not going of the end of the array. In this case a check would suffice:

```
function OnPress()
{
if(i < myArray.length) // check that i is valid
  document.getElementById("story").innerHTML=myArray[i++];
else
  i = 0; // reset i back to start
}
```

Comment: Oh my I am terrible at formatting in comments. Linebreaks don't seem to work :( but yeah my question is how I can get back to the beginning using `else`.

Comment: Ohhh I kept trying myArray[0] and myArray[i]. Okay, thanks so much for your help man.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help. Don't for get to accept an answer once you feel your question has been answered sufficiently btw (the green tick beside the answer you wish to accept) :) Happy hacking.

Answer (score 0):

it's a simple iterator you are looking for.
I wrote onPress not OnPress. you should not write method names with a capital letter.

```
var myArray = [
"Welcome to the Dark Abyss.",
"There's a fork in the road. What to do?",
"The fox doesn't talk much.",
"Thank Grozia! You survived."
];

var current = -1;

function onPress()
{
    current = current >= myArray.length -1 ? 0 : current+1;
    document.getElementById("story").innerHTML=myArray[current];
}
```

Comment: Even though I'm sure that's an easier solution, and I wish I could use it, is there a way to manage the process using a for loop and/or variable counter? Since I haven't learned to code the way you just did, I don't want my professor thinking I'm just copying code from more experienced people.

Answer (score 0):

You will get "undefined" under two situations:

1. IE, which doesn't support Array.indexOf. So you always get "undefined".
2. When i is larger than 4, it will cause "Index out of range" error, so myArray[i++] returns "undefined".

In order to fix the problems, you can try:

1. Set i to 0 at the begining or extend Array.prototype to make Array.indexOf work in IE
2. Whenever i reaches 4, reset it to 0 or myArray.indexOf(myArray[0])(soenke and BIOS already gave you the answer). Or you can use i %= 4.

Code:

```
function OnPress() {
    i %= 4;
    document.getElementById("story").innerHTML = myArray[i++];
}

var myArray = new Array();
myArray[0] = "Welcome to the Dark Abyss.";
myArray[1] = "There's a fork in the road. What to do?";
myArray[2] = "The fox doesn't talk much.";
myArray[3] = "Thank Grozia! You survived.";

var i = 0;
```

Hope it's helpful.